# Inject ConfigService in sub module

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config

I'm new with NestJS and trying to understand the patterns.

I configure ConfigModule to use config set in a specific folder. I want to use that ConfigModule in a submodule but It doesn't work.

I have an app.module

app.module.ts
@Module({
imports: [
ConfigModule.forRoot({
envFilePath: ['.env.local', '.env'],
isGlobal: true,
expandVariables: true,
load: [dbConfiguration, jwtConfiguration],
}),
DatabaseModule,
AuthModule,
UsersModule,
],
controllers: [AppController],
providers: [],
exports: [ConfigModule]
})
export class AppModule {
}

auth.module.ts

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        UsersModule,
        PassportModule,
        ConfigModule,
        JwtModule.registerAsync({
            imports: [ConfigModule],
            useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
                secretOrPrivateKey: configService.get('jwt').secret,
                signOptions: {
                    expiresIn: 3600,
                },
            }),
            inject: [ConfigService],
        }),

    ],
    providers: [AuthService, JwtStrategy],
    exports: [AuthService]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

jwt.strategy.ts

```
import { PassportStrategy } from "@nestjs/passport";
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from "passport-jwt";
import {ConfigService} from "@nestjs/config";

export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
    constructor(configService: ConfigService) {
        console.log(configService);
        super({
            jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
            ignoreExpiration: false,
            secretOrKey: configService.get('jwt').secret,
        })
    }

    async validate(payload: any) {
        return {userId: payload.sub, email: payload.email}
    }
}
```

In the constructor, configService is undefined.

I import ConfigModule in auth.module that contain JwtStrategy.

What did I missed?

Comment: This just saved me hours of debugging. Thanks for asking your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missed the @Injectable() in JwtStrategy